# Persisting data in MS Edge extension

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension

I want o write an extension for Edge where I want to redirect in case of specific site to another site and back in local network.
Unfortunatelly Edge does not persist data nor in sessionStorage, or IndexedDB or in a local variable in the extension after backing from the redirected page, so the two pages play ping-pong with each others.
The extension works in Chrome. I have read somewhere that it is a bug in Edge but I do not know what the workaround is, please.

manifest.js

```
  {
    {
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "name": "PopUp",
     "version": "1.0",
      "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },   
      "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "icons": {
      "16": "icons/logo16.png",
      "32": "icons/logo32.png",
      "48": "icons/logo48.png",
      "128": "icons/logo128.png"
    }
  }
```

background.js

```
const apps = [
  ['AAA', 'AAA/aaa'],
  ['BBB', 'BBB/bbb'],
  ['CCC', 'CCC.xxx.yy']
];

let tabToUrl = new Map();

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        const url = tabs[0].url;
        let domain = (new URL(url));
        domain = domain.hostname.replace('www.','').toLowerCase();
        
        const i = apps.findIndex(u => domain.includes(u[1]));   
        const hasDomain = [...tabToUrl.entries()]
        .filter(({ 1: v }) => v === domain)
        .map(([k]) => k);
        if (i > -1 && hasDomain.length === 0) {
            
            tabToUrl.set(tabs[0].tabId, domain);
            chrome.tabs.update( tabs[0].id, { url: `http://popup.xxx.yy?title=${apps[i][0]}`} ); 
        } 
    });
});
```

[SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69943891/redirection-in-edge-extension)

Comment: How did you test the extension? I tried to install them in chrome and Edge. I tried to check the `sessionStorage` after the page redirected, and I found that they are the same. So I'm afraid I can't determine your issue. If you can provide more details about this problem,such as the steps to reproduce the problem and the specific role of this extension, I think these will help solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, It happens when the redirection is in local network as I have read. It is a bug in Edge. It is very interesting that Edge which works in IE mode uses extension of IE11 (BHO) but it does not work in Edge like it does in IE11. I tried ot localStorage too, but it forget it value after the extension redirect to another site and this site re-redirec back to the original site. Well it is my problem.

Comment: If this is the case, I recommand that you could report this issue to relvant team through the send feedback feature in Edge. Just press `Alt+Shift+i` to edit your problem and send it.

Comment: Thank you Xudong for help.