# Redirection in Edge extension

Tags: cookies, microsoft-edge, session-storage

I made an Edge extension which task is to redirect the page to another site in specific at certain sites and when the user click a button this second site redirect back to the origin.
This extension works in local network but a small error.
The two site redirect to each other continously.
Somewhere I read it that Edge remove sessionStorage and localStorage in case of redirection in local network so I tried cookie but not much success.
Well I ask for help in this case.

```
//background.js
const apps = [
  ['AAA', 'aaa.intra.abc.xx']
];

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        const url = tabs[0].url;
        const domain = (new URL(url)).hostname.replace('www.','').toLowerCase();
        
        try {
                chrome.cookies.get({ 'url': tabs[0].url, 'name': domain }, 
                    function(data){
                        if (!data) {                                
                            const i = apps.findIndex(u => domain.includes(u[1]));
                            if (i > -1) {
                                chrome.cookies.set({
                                    url: tabs[0].url,
                                    name: domain,
                                    value: apps[i][0]
                                });    
                        chrome.tabs.update( tabs[0].id, { url: `http://popup.intra.abc.xx?title=${apps[i][0]}`} ); 
                            }
                        }
                    }   
               );
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Error: " + e);
        }
    });
});
```

**SOLUTION**

manifest.json

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "PopUp",
   "version": "1.0",
    "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] }, 
    "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "cookies", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

background.js

```
const apps = [
  ['AAA', 'aaa.intra.abc.xx']
];

function logURL(requestDetails) {
    const domain = (new URL(requestDetails.url)).hostname.replace('www.','').toLowerCase();
    chrome.cookies.get({ 'url': requestDetails.url, 'name': 'status' }, 
        function(data){
            if (data === null) {    
                const i = apps.findIndex(u => domain.includes(u[1]));
                if (i > -1) {
                    chrome.cookies.set({
                        url: requestDetails.url,
                        name: "status",
                        value: "opened"
                    });
                    const url = 'http://popup.intra.abc.xx/?title=' + apps[i][0];   
                    chrome.tabs.update( requestDetails.tabId, { url: url} );
                }
            }
        }   
    );  
}
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    logURL,
    {urls: ["https://...", "http://.../*", "http://.../*"]},
    ["blocking"]
  );
```

I had to play with the place of URLs because they should had had better place in the manifest.json permissions array but in case of some URLs it caused ping-pong effect again. So they stayed in onBeforeRequest urls array.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the extension console? If possible, can you post an example that reproduces the problem, such as including manifest.js. I think this will help solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you Xudong for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manifest.json

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "PopUp",
   "version": "1.0",
    "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] }, 
    "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "cookies", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

background.js

```
const apps = [
  ['AAA', 'aaa.intra.abc.xx']
];

function logURL(requestDetails) {
    const domain = (new URL(requestDetails.url)).hostname.replace('www.','').toLowerCase();
    chrome.cookies.get({ 'url': requestDetails.url, 'name': 'status' }, 
        function(data){
            if (data === null) {    
                const i = apps.findIndex(u => domain.includes(u[1]));
                if (i > -1) {
                    chrome.cookies.set({
                        url: requestDetails.url,
                        name: "status",
                        value: "opened"
                    });
                    const url = 'http://popup.intra.abc.xx/?title=' + apps[i][0];   
                    chrome.tabs.update( requestDetails.tabId, { url: url} );
                }
            }
        }   
    );  
}
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    logURL,
    {urls: ["https://...", "http://.../*", "http://.../*"]},
    ["blocking"]
  );
```

I had to play with the place of URLs because they should had had better place in the manifest.json permissions array but in case of some URLs it caused ping-pong effect again. So they stayed in onBeforeRequest urls array.